# copy the file and keep full path

Tags: directory, filenames, aix, cp

I need to copy the file to destination folder with it's full path. I can do it on Linux (Red Hat/Centos) easily like this:

```
cp --parents /some/path/to/file /newdir
```

Then I get, in destination directory, something like this:

```
/newdir/some/path/to/file
```

I'd need exactly the same feature on AIX 6.1. I tried few things but didn't succeed yet. Any ideas for handy command to do the job?

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

[AIX's native `cp` utility](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.cmds1/cp.htm) does not include the `--parent` option, as you've discovered.

One option would be to install and use rsync from the [AIX Toolbox for Linux Applications](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/aix-toolbox/) software collection. You'd also need to install the popt RPM (as a dependency of rsync).

Then you could run:

```
rsync -R /some/path/to/file /newdir/
```

To end up with `/newdir/some/path/to/file`.

---

As a home-grown option, you could write a wrapper function using ksh93 (for the array support) to emulate the behavior. Below is a bare-bones function as an example; it assumes you want to copy files with relative paths, and does not support any options:

```
relcp() {
  typeset -a sources=()
  [ "$#" -lt 2 ] && return 1
  while [ "$#" -gt 1 ]
  do
    sources+=("$1")
    shift
  done
  destination=$1

  for s in "${sources[@]}"
  do
    if [ -d "$s" ]
    then
        printf "relcp: omitting directory '%s'\n" "$s"
        continue
    fi

    sdir=$(dirname "$s")
    if [ "$sdir" != "." ] && [ ! -d "$destination/$sdir" ]
    then
      mkdir -p "$destination/$sdir"
    fi
    cp "$s" "$destination/$sdir"
  done

  unset sources s sdir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could install AixTools, a gnu toolkit for AIX. 
http://www.aixtools.net/index.php/coreutils

Which includes cp among all the other tools you know and love.

Answer (score 0):

As a two-step process, creating the target directory first (if it doesn't already exist), and then copying the file (if the `mkdir` succeeded).

```
dir=/some/path/to
mkdir -p "/newdir/$dir" && cp "$dir/file" "/newdir/$dir"
```

As a shell function (only handles copying a single file):

```
cp_parents () {
    source_pathname=$1
    target_topdir=$2

    mkdir -p "$target_topdir/${source_pathname%/*}" && cp "$source_pathname" "$target_topdir/$source_pathname"
}
```

Then,

```
$ cp_parents /some/path/to/file /newdir
```